# Character frame movement in Enchant.js

Tags: javascript, game-engine, enchant

I can't seem to get the frames working. Is there a certain format for this? I have a png, but if I call a certain amount of frames:

```
    this.frame = [2,3,4];
```

The other parts of the animation don't work. Let me know if I need a certain option.

Answer (score 2):

To update the frame sequentially use:

```
this.frame++;
```

What you are doing above is assigning all 3 positions of that array to the frame, afaik only one image can be used at any one time in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any mistake with this frame declaration, did you change it back to other frame ?, did you set a delimiter ? like this :

```
if (game.frame % 3 === 0) { // 3 because the length of the frame is 3
  this.frame = 1; // 1 only examples
}
```